# how to null a variable of type float

Tags: java, android

My code is working if my float variable is set to 0, but I want  my code to work if my  variable is null.  How could I do that?  Here is a code snippet I wrote:

```
float oikonomia= (float)((float)new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString()));

                         if(oikonomia==0){
```

I have tied `if(oikonomia==null)` or `if(oikonomia=null)` but it is not working.

P.S.: Another way would be to initially set `oikonomia=0;` and, if the users change it, go to my if session.  This is not working either.

Float oikonomia = Float.valueOf(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());

```
                     if(oikonomia.toString() == " "){



float oikonomia= (float)((float)new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString()));
                  oikonomia=0;
                         if(oikonomia==0){
```

that way is not working too:

```
Float oikonomia = Float.valueOf(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());

                         if(oikonomia.toString() == " "){
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want a nullable float, then try `Float` instead of `float`

```
Float oikonomia= new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
```

But it will never be `null` that way as in your example...

**EDIT**: Aaaah, I'm starting to understand what your problem is. You really don't know what `vprosvasis7` contains, and whether it is correctly initialised as a number. So try this, then:

```
Float oikonomia = null;

try {
  oikonomia = new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
} 
catch (Exception ignore) {
  // We're ignoring potential exceptions for the example.
  // Cleaner solutions would treat NumberFormatException
  // and NullPointerExceptions here
}

// This happens when we had an exception before
if (oikonomia == null) {
  // [...]
}

// This happens when the above float was correctly parsed
else {
  // [...]
}
```

Of course there are lots of ways to simplify the above and write cleaner code. But I think this should about explain how you should correctly and safely parse a `String` into a `float` without running into any Exceptions...

Answer (score 4):

Floats and floats are not the same thing.  The "float" type in Java is a primitive type that cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be doing something like this

Float oikonomia = Float.valueOf(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());

You're going to get a NumberFormatException if you try to parse a string that doesn't translate into a valid number.  So you could simply wrap this statement in a try catch block and handle the error properly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you please write it with code?i m getting a NumberFormatException..thanks!!:D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Float oikonomia = null;
try{
  oikonomia = Float.valueOf(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
}catch(numberFormatException e){
  // logging goes here
}
```

Now the value is NULL in case of an illegal (non float) string.