# nullable property in android

Tags: android, get, set, nullable

I create a float property that it has get and set methods. When I send null value to the set method , the get method return 0.0 value.
I need null value when I send null to the property .
What should I do?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107368/how-to-null-a-variable-of-type-float

Comment: Thank's ,  but it doesn't work.

Comment: You will have to use Float and not float for this

Comment: I changed the float to Float . But it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you my dear friend. now it work well.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should write Float not float;